# How to rearrange nested list based on particular index

Tags: python, python-2.7, list, nested-lists

I am having a nested list as below:

```
nli=[[123,12],[124,15],[127,19],[12,6]]
```

I want to rearrange the above nested list based on the another list `li`:

```
li=[15,6,12,19]
```

Where `li` values corresponds to the second element of the nested list `nli`So how can I rearrange the `nli` based on the order of the `li` which intern corresponds to the second element of the each nested list `nli`
Output after rearranging `nli` suppose be:

```
[[124, 15], [12, 6], [123, 12], [127, 19]]
```

Also want to know where can I learn more about these kind of operations
Thanks in advance!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can first create a `dict` that maps an element's value to the order in which it appeared in your list `li`.

```
>>> order = {k: i for i, k in enumerate(li)}
>>> order
{19: 3, 12: 2, 6: 1, 15: 0}
```

Then use that `order` to sort the original list based on each `[1]` element.

```
>>> sorted(nli, key = lambda i: order[i[1]])
[[124, 15], [12, 6], [123, 12], [127, 19]]
```

Comment: This should be the most efficient solution.

Answer (score 1):

You can sorted by using the index value of the last element in each value of `nli`:

```
nli=[[123,12],[124,15],[127,19],[12,6]]
li=[15,6,12,19]
new_list = sorted(nli, key=lambda x:li.index(x[-1]))
```

Output:

```
[[124, 15], [12, 6], [123, 12], [127, 19]]
```

Answer (score 1):

Map (create an index) by wanted key first:

```
by_second_item = {item[1]: item for item in nli}
```

Now use the mapping to create the new list:

```
rearranged = [by_second_item[i] for i in li]
# or: list(map(by_second_item.get, li))
```

Answer (score 1):

```
[j for i in li for j in nli if j[1]==i]
#Output
#[[124, 15], [12, 6], [123, 12], [127, 19]]
```